# Run cases within Xunit test in order

Tags: c#, testing, xunit

The following is obviously a toy example, but it illustrates something I want to accomplish in general. I am running ten trials of the same test. I want them to execute in order, i.e. trial 1, then trial 2, and so on. In practice, it starts with trial 3, then does trial 10, then trial 2, then trial 4. I have no idea why it does that.

```
    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(Trials10))]
    public void TwoPlusTwo_Four(int trial)
    {
        var x = 2 + 2;
        Assert.Equal(4, x);
    }

/// <summary>For use as ClassData to repeat Xunit tests</summary>
public class Trials: IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    private readonly int _count;

    public Trials(int count)
    {
        _count = count;
    }

    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= _count; i++)
        {
            yield return new object[] { i };
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}


public class Trials10: Trials
{
    public Trials10(): base(10)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://hamidmosalla.com/2018/08/16/xunit-control-the-test-execution-order/

Comment: Worth noting: if your tests depend on execution order, then something is wrong with your tests. One of the reasons test frameworks randomize execution order by default is that it ensures that your tests have no dependencies between each other - each test should run in isolation.

Comment: It doesn't. It's just nice to see trial 1 first. Ultimately these are Selenium tests with a Web back-end.